# C++ capture-clause equivalent for anonymous lambda functions in C#

Tags: c#, c++, lambda, delegates

I'm currently trying to port over a project I wrote in C++ to a C# framework. I'm running into an issue with passing functions over to another class.

I have a class, PickupDef that takes a delegate function as a paremeter in its constructor. In the C++ version, I would pass over the function like so:

```
[&]() { hero->changeHP(10); }
```

Where hero is a dynamically allocated object in the calling class. I've tried using this in the C# version:

```
delegate { hero.changeHP(10); }
```

But C# doesn't recognize the hero object. It seems like I can't scope it to take in references from the calling class.

Is there a way to get the functionality of the C++ `[&]()` in C#? I could pass a reference to the hero object to the PickupDef but that would require an overhaul of the current system.

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example of something that doesn't work. We should be able to easily test it ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda in C# is written like so:

```
() => hero.changeHP(10);
```

As this is a parameterless lambda, you can pass it around as an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) instance e.g.

```
Action setHpTo10 = () => hero.changeHP(10);
```

Lambdas inherently capture the variable that you are referencing in C#.